# Fields commutator, a concise review

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, commutator

I am entering in the quantum filed theory world, and I am consulting many notes, but something is a bit unclear about commutators.

Hence I would like some expert of you tell me what exactly (if meaningful) do the following relations ensure or violate or mean.

I will call $\phi$ and $\pi$ two different fields, and $x, y$ two different spatial coordinates, as well as $t, t'$ are two different times.

$$[\phi(x, t), \phi(x, t)] = ??$$

$$\color{blue}{[\phi(x, t), \phi(y, t)] = 0}$$

$$[\phi(x, t), \phi(x, t')] = ??$$

$$[\phi(x, t), \phi(y, t')] = ??$$

$$[\phi(x, t), \pi(x, t)] = ??$$

$$[\phi(x, t), \pi(y, t)] = ??$$

$$[\phi(x, t), \pi(x, t')] = ??$$

$$[\phi(x, t), \pi(y, t')] = ??$$

P.s. Sorry if this questions seems to be silly or redundant or else. But it will really help me in understanding situations and computations meanings, also for what concerns causality or micro causality.

Comment: If phi and pi are just two different fields, then one cannot know. Prob pi is supposed to be the canonical momentum assoziated with phi through a hamiltonian?

Comment: The answers to half of these are just “a horrible mess”. If you have a specific thing you want to use these commutators for, just tell us!